# API not working properly after deploying on heroku

Tags: python, selenium, flask

Hello everyone i recently made a python script which downloads video from youtube using selenium so i tried to convert that script into an API and deployed it on heroku at first it worked perfectly (but only once or twice) now i get diffrent errors everytime i enter the url i get from heroku when i check the logs sometimes it says that the "memory quota exceeded" sometime it says "no such element is found" i.e selenium error and other times it runs so i am not sure what really casuing this here is the code:-

```
import flask
from flask import request
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    url = request.args['url']
    mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "iPhone 6/7/8" }
    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    op.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
    op.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    op.add_argument("--headless")
    op.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    op.add_argument("--disable-dev-sh-usage")
    driver = 
    webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"),chrome_options=op)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.refresh()
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/video')
    video_source = element.get_attribute('src')
    return video_source
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: It seems that you are not closing browser with driver.quit() and that is why at start worked nice, but later fails, as driver is using ram

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few things that could be improved.

1/

This is a bad xpath:

```
'/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/video'
```

You don't want to use a full path because if anything in the DOM structure changes between `html` and the `video` tags it will fail.
If you can share the DOM for the video element I can help you create a new one.

2/
You do this

```
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.refresh()
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/video')
```

You wait 3 seconds - but what if the page takes 4 seconds?  (the answer is it fails). There is no dynamic synchronisation that the object is ready and available.

Additionally, do you need to refresh? - that's a browser refresh to reloads the page. It's essentially going to the page twice.

Have a look at selenium wait strategies [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

If you're getting NoSuchElement, you can try an implicit wait:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  
# add this only once - it polls for up to 10 seconds and moves on when ready
```

If you're getting ElementNotIteractable (or such) you can try an explicit wait:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/video")))
#(but also update the xpath)
```

You will want to review that selenium docs link to find the appropriate expected condition.

3/
By default `--headless` creates a tiny browser window. IF your page has dynamic scaling it will impact xpaths.

Set the window size to your expected resolution:

```
op.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
```

Comment: thanks a lot man i made the changes that you told me and now its working completely fine atleast for now hahaha thanks a lot